# How do I create an aggregate view of products i've purchased? (Commerce)

Tags: views, commerce

How do I get an aggregate view of all products i've purchased?

I'm specifically looking to show only one field from the products, "file".  My use-case is that I have a course registration site using Drupal Commerce, Views, Commerce_Registration, etc.  Each course (product) has a non-visible field "file" which I want to aggregate in a view.

Any direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Clone the order history & modify as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RajeevK.  I've cloned order history and begun modifying to suit my needs.

My first step was to add the "Commerce Order: Line items" relationship.  This was fine, and order history still displays.

My second step was to add the "Commerce Line Item: Product" relationship.  This made it so that no results are returned to the user, even though he has order history, can see the product page, and checkout with that product.

Do you have any idea why this second relationship would break the order history results?

Comment: Think I may have answered my own question- "View Products of any type" permission.  Thanks for your help!